# Scaling formula (reference required)

Tags: references, item-response-theory, scaled

I came across a very good scaling formula to scale theta based on Item Response Theory to the scale of 31-68.

The original post is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155651/what-is-the-correct-method-for-standardising-scores-1-to-1-ideally-in-r). The formula looks like this:

$f(x) = \frac{(b-a)(x-min)}{max-min} + a$

Would anyone kindly point out where I can find this type of scaling in a book or journal article because I need to cite it from such publications?

Comment: You could probably find a high school math textbook you could cite! I guess any could do.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t imagine that the formula to rescale a variable from one range to another has earned a publication, because it’s rather intuitive. It’s also not specific to IRT. You first scale the variable to [0, 1], then stretch it out to [a, b].

If you still feel the urge to cite that formula, there’s a “Cite” button on the Cross Validated answer you linked to.